# serial SC16IS752 bitshift error in transferred byte after 30sec delay/timeout

Tags: serial-port, embedded-linux

I am working on a SC16IS752 chip in our embedded Linux design. The chip works great on both COM ports under normal conditions of serial activity. We have found, however, that within a serial session, when you don't send or receive data for approximately 30 seconds, the next byte transmitted on the TX line is bitshifted in all baud rates 38400 and above. Interestingly this problem doesn't occur at 19k baud or below (slower baud rates).

The problem gets worse at higher baud rates. At 38k baud, the transmitted byte is shifted 1 bit (try to send 0x66 and 0xB3 gets sent). At 115k baud, the transmitted byte is shifted 4 bits (try to send 0x66 and 0xF6 gets sent).

This problem only occurs after 30sec of inactivity in an existing serial session. Meaning the first byte of a new serial session is always transmitted correctly.

If you wait for the 30sec and instead receive a byte on the NXP chip, this somehow puts the NXP chip in a good state where a subsequent transmitted byte is transmitted correctly (so long as it takes place less than 30sec later than the received byte).

I have poured through the SC16IS752 datasheet, application notes, and errata to no avail. I have investigated sleep modes, receive timeouts, and all the status registers. I have also tried clearing the transmit fifos before transmitting data. I have run out of things to try and debug. I know for a fact that I am getting the correct byte sent via SPI to the NXP serial chip, from the debugging in my Linux driver.

By the way, the Linux driver that I'm using was written by Manuel Stahl which he posted on the Linux Kernel Mailing list in an (unsuccessful) attempt to get it into the linux kernel.

Later investigation revealed the following:

We have hooked up an inline-RS-232 device which shows the state of all pins using LEDs.  I have noticed that our SC16 serial chip (configured as a DTE), will have its "TD" and "RTS" lights active for 32seconds after a Tx or Rx transaction at which point both the TD and RTS lights go off.

This means the SC16 chip has a 32 second timeout at which point it deactivates those pins.  At that point, a Tx transaction (having the SC16 chip send data) will result in the bitshift problem (as before, it is only the first byte that is bitshifted).

Here is the interesting part:  Using a debug laptop with Windows and "RealTerm" connected as the CTE (on the other end of the SC16 serial connection), it allows us to toggle the "CTS" pin.  When I toggle this pin (either ON or OFF), it "wakes up" the TD and RTS lights from the SC16 chip at which point a Tx transaction (having the SC16 chip send data) will be successful!

So the summary is:

- When the SC16 chip has its TD and RTS lights on, subsequent Tx transactions are successful.
- The SC16 TD and RTS lights timeout (turn off) after 32 seconds.  Subsequent Tx transactions have a bitshift problem.
- When I tickle the SC16 chip by toggling the CTE's RTS pin, it "wakes up" the SC16 chip's TD and RTS lights, subsequent Tx transactions are successful.

I see nothing in the SC16 datasheet that mentions this type of timeout.  The only mention is "sleep mode" which I have disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  The problem is that we are using a ISL4270E RS232 level converter (rather than the SP3243E that is used in the SC16IS752 Demo Board) which supports a auto powerdown feature where it powers the chip down after 30sec of inactivity.  The problem occurs when it detects data and powers up, it doesn't do so fast enough to send all bits at 115k baud.  This is why the bitshift problem is worse at higher baud rates.